# php - how to get content with login information

Tags: php, post, curl

I want to use PHP to get this html content, the final aim I want to get m3u8 link
It requires log-in
http://tv24.vn/livetv/vtv1.html
This is information to test:
user: h2132704@trbvm.com
pass: 12345678
I tried to use curl POST but unsuccessful!

```
<?php
$username = 'h2132704@trbvm.com';
$password = '12345678';
$loginUrl = 'http://tv24.vn/livetv/';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$store = curl_exec($ch);

$return=file_get_contents("http://tv24.vn/livetv/vtv1.html"); preg_match('/file: "(.*?)"/', $return, $m3u8);
echo $m3u8;
?>
```

Any solution?
Thanks much !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it

```
$username = 'h2132704%40trbvm.com';
$password = '12345678';
$url = 'http://tv24.vn/account/login';


//login form action url
$postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;

$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://tv24.vn/livetv/vtv1.html");
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('/file: "(.*?)"/', $html, $m3u8);

print_r($m3u8[1]);

curl_close($ch);
```